# Python The inner product is <function innerproduct at 0x000001EF5A6A7D30> error

Tags: python, for-loop, sum, range, inner-product

My code is below, but I'm getting this weird output for my inner product code and don't know why it's not calculating the correct inner product. nums and nums2 ask the user for an equal list of numbers in which the inner product will be calculated. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
def innerproduct(nums, nums2):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sum += nums[i] * nums2[i]
    return innerproduct
```

Comment: In your own words, where you have `return innerproduct`, *what do you expect that to mean*? Show an example of how you call the function, and trace through, step by step, exactly what you expect to happen and why.

Comment: Hint: What is the name of the variable that you use to store the result of the calculation? Is that result the thing you want to `return`? Then, what should your `return` statement look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error arising because of the `return innerproduct` statement since that is the name of the function.

Instead, did you mean to return the sum?

```py
def innerproduct(nums, nums2):
    sum = 0.0
    for i in range(len(nums)):
        sum += nums[i] * nums2[i]
    return sum
```

Comment: This worked! Weird, I thought I tried this already, but I guess I didn't. Thanks

Comment: @anthonypollarco Could you also mark the answer as accepted since it helped.

Comment: Can't accept answer until  after a certain time period

Comment: Don't use the names of built-ins (`sum`) as variable names. `total` would be better

Answer (score 1):

That's not "weird output", it's exactly what you told it to return.  You ignored the result and returned a reference to the function object.

Try this instead:

```
result = 0
for i in range(len(nums)):
    result += nums[i] * nums2[i]
return result
```

Note: do *not* give a variable the same name as a built-in type or function.

You can do this more directly with the built-in `sum` function:

```
return sum(nums[i] * nums2[i] for i in range(len(nums)))
```

Or perhaps even better:

```
return sum(a * b for a, b in zip(nums, nums2[i]))
```